# Laptop Series Battery Compatibility

Tags: laptop, battery

I need to replace my Toshiba Satellite L655-13X battery with a new one. The batteries I found are for L655-S5083, and L655-S5150. They appear to be the same in the picture to my battery. However, how can I confirm? The description doesn't say anything about compatibility with other models.

So my question is: how to know if all Toshiba Satellite L655-* are the same in terms of battery physical structure?

I understand that I need to have the exact same voltage. More mAh and/or Wh is better. The problem is with the size.

Also, I noticed a replace/model no, that goes like: PA3817U-1BAS. The "BAS" might be found "BR". What's the difference? And what's this number in the first place?

Comment: I would contact Toshiba, and have them provide you a list of compatible OEM part numbers, then contact the seller to confirm the battery is a replacement for one of those part numbers.  This way if it does not work, you have written proof, the seller confirmed it was indeed a replacement. This answer will be extremely difficult for anyone except Toshiba to answer, unless Toshiba offers this information on their website, based on recent experience that likely isn't the case.

Comment: PA3817U-1BAS is a toshiba direct replacement part number, according to walmart those 2 part numbers will work>>>>https://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/Superb-Choice-6-cell-Battery-for-Toshiba-Satellite-L655-S5103-L655-S5150-L655-S5153/PRD722QC8JPCC4M